# How can I trigger an onmouseover from another function?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

In one function, having nothing to do with another item, how can I trigger an onmouseover event in javascript on a div with id 'item'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply call the `onmouseover` function of that element:

```
document.getElementById("item").onmouseover()
```

`document.getElementById("item")` refers to the element, *`elem`*`.onmouseover` to the function for the [*mouseover* event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseover) and appending `()` to it will call that function.

Comment: Unless, you have a container element that relies on event bubbling.